# Adding custom css to bootstrap react header

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to add custom css to the following code

When I set `.custom-navbar { color: white; }` in my CSS the text in my header continues to be black. I also want to make the Navbar.brand sit in the middle of the tabs on each side using a flex container, but the css I write does not seem to work with the boostrap.

How can I customize my header?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Container, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Logo from '../assets/image.svg'
import './newheader.css' 

const Head = () => {
    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="transparent" variant="white" className="custom-navbar">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><img class='logo' src={Logo} alt='Luminous' width='60%'></img></Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Get Address</Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown title="How it Works" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Steps</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Rates</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Support</NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
              <Nav.Link href="#deets">Login</Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown title="" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Arabic</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Spanish</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
              <Button eventKey={2} href="#memes">Sign Up</Button>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    )
}


export default Head;
```

I tried writing the css but the changes I wanted to see didn't appear

Comment: Please prevent rendered HTML and the relevant CSS. It's very difficult to debug JSX. Once you have a solution you can back-port it to your React app.

Comment: The answer probably has to do simply with  CSS specificity. Try changing your selector to `.navbar.custom-navbar`, or add `body ` in front to increase precedence.